# OpenCV get image rotation and tilt ,inclination

Tags: opencv, rotation, tilt

Hi all anyone has any idea on how to get image rotation and tilt with respect to the vertical image in OpenCV
for example here  [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvI3a.jpg)

how can a get alfa end tilt(inclination) with respect to the recognized image

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Homography between the a perfectly "vertical" image and the image captured. This is a widely studied problem and you should be able to use OpenCV's `findHomography` method to do this. You would need some kind of feature descriptors as well - look at SIFT descriptors.